# SQL Server query without using cursor

Tags: sql-server

I have data in a table and need to populate the min and max range for the row number column.

This is my input table:

[image]

I would like to have the following output table result without using a cursor:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want `lag()`?

```
select t.*,
       lag(rownumber, 1, 0) over (order by rownumber) as rownumber_min,
       rownumber as rownumber_max
from t;
```